# Display android app in pull down menu but not in status bar

Tags: android

I am building an android application that I would like to provide access from the Notification Bar but I don't want it to display as a Notification Item in the status bar at the top. It should only show up when the user pull's down the bar.

Is there any way to get one without the other?

Comment: are you talking about the notification??

Comment: Yes, thanks. The question has been adjusted accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NotificationCompat` with `setPriority` as `PRIORITY_MIN`